# Linux Script: Saving Memory print into text file via Crontab always blank

Tags: linux, bash, memory, cron

In my CentOS, i'm trying to print the CPU USAGE and FREE MEMORY output numbers into a text file. But when i typing in the terminal, it is all fine. But when it is executed via the `crontab` the MEMORY output is always blank.

Manually typing in terminal:

```
# echo CPU: `top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`, RAM: `awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)` >> ~/stats.txt
# cat ~/stats.txt
CPU: 3.8, RAM: 1307
```

Same command in Crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * echo CPU: `top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`, RAM: `awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)` >> ~/stats.txt
```

Then inside the Text file:

```
# cat ~/stats.txt
CPU: 3.4, RAM: 
CPU: 4.1, RAM: 
CPU: 3.9, RAM:
```

Why is the **RAM** output always blank please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using process substitution in your command:

```
<(free -m)
```

.  This is a Bash feature that is not present in the standard POSIX shell, and not even in Bash on some platforms.

Unless you specify otherwise by setting the `SHELL` variable in your crontab, `cron` runs your commands via `/bin/sh`.  When started this way, `bash` does its best to emulate the POSIX shell in most respects.  That includes refusing to recognize process substitutions.  On my present system, for example:

```
$ /bin/bash -c "awk '/^Mem/ {print \$4}' <(free -m)"
11603
```

but

```
$ /bin/sh -c "awk '/^Mem/ {print \$4}' <(free -m)"
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)'
```

Since your command is (presumably) producing an error, it may be that `cron` is sending you email about that.

You could set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your crontab, but I don't see why you need process substitution in the first place.  `awk` reads from standard input if you don't specify a file name, so you could as easily pipe the output of `free` into it.

```
$ /bin/sh -c "free -m | awk '/^Mem/ {print \$4}'"
11612
```

The corresponding crontab line would be

```
*/10 * * * * echo CPU: `top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`, RAM: `free -m | awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}'` >> ~/stats.txt
```

That's more standard, easier (for me) to read, and more internally consistent.